# Windows bacth scripting: Problem exporting variable to txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, export

I have a variable with html code (having major, minor symbols)
and I need it to be exported and appended to a txt

```
set WORD1=^<p^>^<strong^>PROBLEM^</strong^> with something;n^</p^>
```

I can't echo the variable like this

```
echo %WORD1%
```

And I need to export it/append it to a file. I used:

```
echo %WORD1% >body.txt
```

But this generates an error as the variable has minor/Major symbol

If I double quote the variable, the exported text is exported with double quotes (and obviusly this is not what i need)

Comment: What is the actual content of `%WORD1%`?

Comment: <p><strong>PROBLEM</strong> with something;n</p>   if I double quote the variable and echo it, it appears: "<p><strong>PROBLEM</strong> with something;n</p>"

Comment: Yes, echo uses `"` as literals... What do you mean *major/minor symbol*?

Comment: If that is the whole string, try `set WORD1=^^^<p^>^^^<strong^^^>PROBLEM^</strong^> with something;n^^^</p^^^>`

Comment: major/minor symbol <>

Answer (score 0):

To *define* the variable, use:

```
set "WORD1=<p><strong>PROBLEM</strong> with something;n</p>"
```

To "export" the variable, use:

```
(
set /P "=%WORD1%"
echo/
) > body.txt < NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a variable in a safe way you need to enclose the whole assignment expression in quotation marks:

```cmd
set "WORD1=<p><strong>PROBLEM</strong> with something;n</p>"
```

This avoids the need of [escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), unless the string itself contains quotation marks on its own.

Note that this syntax only works with [command extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) enabled, but this is the default in Command Prompt anyway.

---

To return/expand an arbitrary string in a safe manner, even when it contains quotation marks on its own, is to use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
echo(!WORD1!
```

To safely write the output to a file, place the [redirection expression](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) at the front:

```cmd
> "body.txt" echo(!WORD1!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this on one line:

```batch-file
set "WORD1=<p><strong>PROBLEM</strong> with something;n</p>"&&>body.txt cmd/v/cecho.!WORD1!

rem :: Or, without defining a previous variable, if it is not necessary:

>body.txt <nul set/P "=<p><strong>PROBLEM</strong> with something;n</p>"
```